# Determine whether child directive is nested within parent directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive and I want it to use a different `templateUrl:` depending on whether it is wrapped by a `parentDirective`.  The fourth argument (parent controller) of the child's `link:` function would seem to be the place to determine whether there is a parent controller because `require: ?^parentDirective` returns `null` if the parent isn't found, but I can't seem to figure out how to translate this to the `templateUrl` selection.  My understanding of  `$compile` is that I can use `templateUrl: function()` but I can't seem to get it to work.  Perhaps I'm having scope issues.

```
link: function(scope, element, attributes, parentCtrl) {
    ...
    scope.wrapped = function() {
            return parentCtrl ? true : false;
        }
}
```

Comment: What if you check if the elem.parent() (or it's parents) has the parent directive? You only have access to the `?^parentDirective` object in the link function, but you need to know that before the link runs in the templateUrl function

Comment: Check this out http://plnkr.co/edit/sAvsycXavbJ5er1xdQYy?p=preview

Comment: @JoseM Very nice (contrived and simple) example.  Thanks for that.  I'm going to play around with another option too and see what I come up with.  I suppose the recursive crawling of the DOM wouldn't be too heavy though.

Comment: If you're selectively compiling a template, i'd avoid manual compilation in favor of using ng-if / ng-include within the template itself. Recursive compilation can be tricky.

Comment: @pixelbits suggestion can also work and then you can rely on some scope variable that you set in your link function.  I actually like it better, here is my sample changed to use that logic: http://plnkr.co/edit/CzAAre93YZm4qnAa6b8n?p=preview (this was pixelbits idea, not mine)

Comment: That's exactly what I did: ng-include in the template.  Figured it out last night using template: but @pixelbits comment made me reconsider and use a single template with the ng-include instead.  Thanks!  I'll post code later this afternoon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the input.  Here's what I ended up doing.  The template is dynamic and configures itself based on whether the parentCtrl is defined in the link function.

**Directive:**

```
...
templateUrl: 'path/to/template.html',
link: function(scope, element, attributes, parentCtrl) {
    if (parentCtrl) {
        scope.wrapped = true;
    } else {
        scope.wrapped = false;
    }
}
...
```

**Template:**

`<div ng-if="!wrapped" ng-click="someAction()">Do Action</div>`